# Inno Setup Jumps to Second Page if Program is Installed

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal

On first install everything runs smooth, but if I run the installer again it just jumps to the second page asking where i want to put the additional files, and then in the ready page only the parameters for the additional files folders is shown. The ignore version flag is set, what else could it be?

[image: image showing ready page ignoring main app]

```
[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
OutputBaseFilename=aeolian_meditation_setup
WizardSmallImageFile=compiler:greenlogo.bmp
WizardImageFile=compiler:glogo.bmp
DirExistsWarning=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
;Main program that will be installed in {app} folder
Source: "D:\ocean_swift\Flowstone Projects\Aeolian Meditation Advanced\OS Aeolian Meditation Advanced A191.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

;Database file that will installed where user choosed
Source: "D:\ocean_swift\Flowstone Projects\Aeolian Meditation Advanced\onts\OpenSans-Regular.ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; FontInstall: "Open Sans"
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\VSTPlugins\OS Aeolian Meditation Advanced A191.dll"; DestDir: "{code:GetDataDir}"

[Code]
var
  DataDirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // Create the page

  DataDirPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir,
    'Select 32bit VST Plugin Directory', 'Where should the 32bit VSTi plugin be installed??',
    'Select the folder in which Setup should install the 32bit VSTi plugin, then click Next.',
    False, '');
  DataDirPage.Add('');

  DataDirPage.Values[0] := 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VSTPlugins\';
end;

procedure RegisterPreviousData(PreviousDataKey: Integer);
begin
  // Store the selected folder for further reinstall/upgrade
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'DataDir', DataDirPage.Values[0]);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // Set default folder if empty
  if DataDirPage.Values[0] = '' then
     DataDirPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{sd}\DataDir');
  Result := True;
end;

function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo,
  MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
var
  S: String;
begin
  // Fill the 'Ready Memo' with the normal settings and the custom settings
  S := '';

  S := S + MemoDirInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

  S := S + '32bit VSTi' + NewLine;
  S := S + Space + DataDirPage.Values[0] + NewLine;

  Result := S;
end;

function GetDataDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  { Return the selected DataDir }
  Result := DataDirPage.Values[0];
end;
```

Comment: It may help if you describe what is your "Second page", as there's no fixed set of pages. - Anyway, I'm pretty sure that the duplicate question explains what you need.

Comment: first page - chose a path for program installation.
second page - chose a path for extra files

Comment: DisableDirPage=no solved it! i'm not sure it is an exact duplicate, but ok, as long as it is solved. thanks!

Comment: Yes I indicated there were other disabled flags in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_disableprogramgrouppage.htm) you will see that the default value for `DisableProgramGroupPage` is `auto`. As described there:

> If this is set to `auto`, at startup Setup will look in the registry to
>   see if the same application is already installed, and if so, it will
>   not show the *Select Start Menu Folder* wizard page.

If you review the other `Disable` entries in the help file you will see them behave the same. It is logical to only show these pages during a new install. Change the default behaviour by setting these to `no`.

Comment: setting this does not work. DisableProgramGroupPage=no

Comment: Can you show us your log?

Comment: following your answer and martin's comment on the other post together i managed to solve it by setting also DisableDirPage=no. marked you as correct